# не магу понять как правильно добавление или удаление класса связать с state

Tags: reactjs

если я правильно понял любое изменение в UI должно происходит через state (изменился state, UI перерисовалось)... есть меню-бургер он меняется по клику с X на -- как тут использовать state? или тут вообще нету смысла использовать state?

```
const Burger = (props) => {
const [state, setState] = useState('')
const toggleHandler = (event) => {
    event.target.classList.toggle('active')
}
return (
    <div 
    className="my"
    onClick={toggleHandler}
    ></div>
)
}
```

вот такое решение правильно или нету смысла

```
const Burger = (props) => {
const [isPressed, setPressed] = useState(false)
const toggleHandler = (event) => {
    setPressed(!isPressed)
    if(isPressed){
        event.target.classList.add('active')
    }
    else{
        event.target.classList.remove('active')
    }
}
return (
    <div 
    className="my"
    onClick={toggleHandler}
    ></div>
)
```

}

Comment: а так не работает?

Comment: @azlov работает прекрасно НО нету состояния это просто решение нативным js

Comment: а какая необходимость хранить имена классов в стейте?

Comment: @azlov это мой первый проект на react и мне желательно получить ответы пока что я не в состоянии отвечать на вопросы да и я не пытаюсь имя класса сохранить в state... у кнопки же есть состояние нажат(Х) или нет(--) мне надо понять надо ли такое реализовать через state и как

Comment: у вас в вопросе только про добавление/удаление классов через стейт сказано. что значит *нажат(Х) или нет(--)*

Comment: @azlov вы сначала прочтите и то что под вопросом потом поймете что за X и что за --

Comment: нету смысла. скажите, что изменилось после того, как вы стали использовать стейт?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113030/discussion-between-armen-and-azlov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ui изменяется при изменении состояния или пропсов, для изменения классов у элемента как беспрактис можно использо библиотеку [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames). Для изменения элемента напрямую можно использовать [реферансы](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), но не надо злоупотреблять им, подробнее можешь прочитать в дорументации. В общем для самого примитивного примера могу показать такой код на основии твоего

```js
const Burger = () => {

  const [isPressed, setPressed] = useState(false)

  const handleToggle = () => setPressed(!isPressed)

  return (
      <button 
        className={isPressed ? 'active': ''}
        onClick={toggleHandler}
      >Button</button>
  )
  
}
```